# Find/replace after PHP code has been applied

Tags: php, javascript, replace

I'm trying to build a PHP form that outputs custom JSON code.

Take a look: http://s194239704.onlinehome.us/bcembed/

The JSON code output that the app creates is wrong. I need to do a search and replace to remove some of the commas.

The (partial) source code looks like this:

```
{
<!-- ALBUM ART --><span <?php if($artdisplay!="block") echo "style=\"display:none;\""; ?>>"art": { "x": <?php echo $artx; ?>, "y": <?php echo $arty; ?>, "w": <?php if($artsize=="small") {echo "100";} elseif($artsize=="large") {echo "150";} ?>, "h": <?php if($artsize=="small") {echo "100";} elseif($artsize=="large") {echo "150";} ?>, "show": true },</span>
<!-- MAINTEXT --><span <?php if($maintextdisplay!="block") echo "style=\"display:none;\""; ?>>"maintext": { "x": <?php echo $maintextx; ?>, "y": <?php echo $maintexty; ?>, "w": <?php echo $maintextw; ?>, "h": <?php echo $maintexth; ?>, "show": true, "styles": { "fontSize": "<?php echo $maintextfontsize; ?>", "textAlign": "<?php echo $maintextalign; ?>", <?php if($maintextbold=="bold") echo "\"fontWeight\": \"" . $maintextbold . "\","; ?> <?php if($maintextitalic=="italic") echo "\"fontStyle\": \"" . $maintextitalic . "\","; ?> }},</span>
}
```

I want to run the search/replace after the PHP is applied. I tried wrapping the whole thing in a JavaScript search/replace, because I thought the PHP would run before the Javascript code. But nothing happened.

Can you tell I'm in over my head? Half-assed copy and pasting can only get me so far...

---

**Edit: I didn't know about json_encode.** It seems to be working, but I ran into another snag. I want to have this as the output:

```
"currenttime": {
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "w": 30,
  "h": 30,
  "show": true,
  "styles": {
    "fontSize": "13",
    "fontWeight": "bold",
    "fontStyle": "null",
    "textAlign": "center"
  }
}
```

And this is the code I'm trying to use:

```
$jsonData['currenttime'] = array(
  'x' => $currenttimex,
  'y' => $currenttimey,
  'w' => $currenttimew,
  'h' => $currenttimeh,
  'show' => $currenttimedisplay=="block" ? true : false,
  ['styles'] = array(
    'fontSize' => $currenttimefontsize,
    'fontWeight' => $currenttimebold,
    'fontStyle' => $currenttimeitalic,
    'textAlign' => $currenttimealign
  )
);
```

It's like I need a sub-array for the styles... what's the right way to format this?

Comment: Is there a reason youre manually writing the json instead of using the `json_encode` php function?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not store the data in an array and simply `json_encode()` it at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youre essentially ok, but you have some syntax mistakes:

```
$jsonData['currenttime'] = array(
  'x' => $currenttimex,
  'y' => $currenttimey,
  'w' => $currenttimew,
  'h' => $currenttimeh,
  'show' => $currenttimedisplay =="block" ? true : false,
  'styles' => array(
    'fontSize' => $currenttimefontsize,
    'fontWeight' => $currenttimebold,
    'fontStyle' => $currenttimeitalic,
    'textAlign' => $currenttimealign
  )
);
```

---

I wouldnt manually with this... use `json_encode` instead:

```
$jsonData = array();

$jsonData['art'] = array(
  'x' => $artx,
  'y' => $arty,
  'w' => $artsize=="small" ? 100 : ($artsize == 'large' ? 150 : null),
  'h' => $artsize=="small" ? 100 : ($artsize == 'large' ? 150 : null),
  'show' => true
);

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This array structure works, but I need to add a sub-array. See my edited post above for code examples.

Comment: Youre n the right track with your update... your syntax is just off... see my update.